# Navbar padding issue

Tags: css

So I have this issue where my Navbar splits itself based on the specified padding. Easier to see what I mean below.

[image: example]

As you can see I have an extra **blank** menu item which after some time I was able to narrow down to it being caused by the padding.

[image: example2]

Above is with 0 padding. How can I keep the Navbar height along with fixing the menu?

```
li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #EAE0D2;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Specifically**:

> padding: 20px; **(image1)** padding: 0px; **(image 2)**

**Snippet**

```css
#menu {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 width: 1080px;
 margin-top: 5%;
 list-style-type: none;
 background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
 overflow: hidden;
}

li {
 flex: 1;
 border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}

li:last-child {
 border: none;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font: Verdana;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #EAE0D2;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
}

li a:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(#404040, #3E3E3E);
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="art.html">ART</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. This is your markup & styles with 20px padding on the `<li>`s and it looks OK to me: https://jsfiddle.net/tf8d6mak/ Any chance you can make a pen or fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Essentially I was under the impression padding was the only option I had to create menu thickness. The answer below shows an alternative using a line. My padding value just continued to "push" down my menu item and making a ghost button. If that makes sense?

Comment: I would need to see the bug reproduced to diagnose it. As you can see in the fiddle linked in my previous comment I was able to add padding to the `.li a` elements and it worked as I would expect it to. In any case, it sounds like the answer you received solved the issue for you.

Comment: @JonathanNicol If you are still curious, as I am, take a look at this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nwyzve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Want was your problem? (My assumption)**
First check this **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/rYJKeB)**

You were assigning `padding` property to `li a:hover`, instead of `li a`.

As it's possible to achieve the desired result by adding padding to `li a` and other way is by assigning `line-height` to either `li`/`#menu`.

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1080px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #EAE0D2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#404040, #3E3E3E);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="art.html">ART</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That fixed the issue, any chance you can explain to me what WAS happening and what is now happening? How is adding a line an alternative to padding?

Comment: @KevinP. check the edited answer, let me know if that was your problem.

Comment: I had my padding placed in the appropriate selector (li a). I am still confused as to why padding would have "pushed" down the first menu item rather than actually just putting a padding around the entirety.

Comment: fork my codepen and replace your code, save it and post it here. I will take a look.

Comment: haha. very simple error. You forgot to close the `<a>` in the header. Close it with `</a>`. Things will be fine :)